# featherjs error: No authentication strategies allowed for creating a JWT (`jwtStrategies`)

Tags: jwt, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

After migrating to featherjs V4 (CROW) following the guide (https://crow.docs.feathersjs.com/migrating.html) the authentication no longer works.

Right after the migration to V4 i received an error that @featherjs/authentication-oauth was missing (even if i do not use oauth at all) so i installed the missin module.

Now i get the error: 
featherjs error: No authentication strategies allowed for creating a JWT (`jwtStrategies`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind it has been fixed in version 4.0.0-pre.1.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this while migrating... my issue was I had a config file with `authentication.strategies` instead of `authentication.authStrategies`

https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/migrating.html#old-client-jwt-compatibility